# $T:V\rightarrow V$ is given, finding a base $C$ for $V$ such that $[T]_C = A$ when $A$, $B$ another base for $V$ and $[T]_B$ are given

Tags: linear-algebra

The question I tried to solve is has followed:

$T:\mathbb{R}^2[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2[x]$ is defined:

- $T(1) = 1-3x^2$
- $T(1+x) = a+1+4x$
- $T(1+x^2) = -2x^2-2$.

Let $A$ =

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6 & -3 \\
0 & 4 & 0 \\
-3 & 6 & b\\ 
\end{bmatrix}

Find for which $a,b$ there **exists** a base $C$ satisfying $[T]_C = A$.

So I was trying to explicitly find a base $C$, but didn't succeed. What I had manged to do is:

Using the given $T$ one gets:

- $T(x) = 3x^4 + 4x + a$
- $T(x^2) = x^2 -3$

So in case I choose $b=1$ and  $C=\{c_1 ,c_2 ,c_3\}$ when $c_1 = 1$ , $c_2 = (\alpha\cdot 1 + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2)$ , $c_3 = x^2$, I got:

- $T(1) = 1\cdot 1 + 3\cdot x^2$
- $T(x^2) = -3\cdot 1 + 1\cdot x^2$

Now to get $c_2$ I need $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$ which satisfies:

$T(\alpha\cdot 1 + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2) = 6\cdot 1  + 4\cdot (\alpha \cdot 1 + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2) + 6\cdot x^2 
 \Rightarrow $
$\alpha T(1) + \beta T(x) +\gamma T(x^2) = 6\cdot 1  + 4\cdot (\alpha \cdot 1 + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2) + 6\cdot x^2 $
$\Rightarrow$
$\alpha(1-3x^2) + \beta (a+1+4x) + \gamma (-2x^2 -2) = 6\cdot 1  + 4\cdot (\alpha \cdot 1 + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot x^2) + 6\cdot x^2 $

After simplifying the equation and using  one gets three equations:

1. $\alpha + \beta \cdot a -3\gamma = 6 +4\alpha$
2. $4\beta = 4\beta$
3. $-3\alpha + 3\beta + \gamma = 6 + 4\gamma$

so from $1 , 3$ we get that $\beta \cdot a - 3\beta = 0 \Rightarrow a =3$. So $a=3 , b=1$ satisfying the existence of a base $C$ as asked for, but is there a simple way to find the base $C$ explicitly? are there more $a,b$ for which there exists a base $C$ has satisfying the above conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
Note that $E=(1,1+x,1+x^2)$ is a basis of $\mathbb R[x]_2$, then $\mathcal T$ is totally determined, and the matrix $\boldsymbol B$ of $\mathcal T$ under $E$ is given as well. How do matrices $\boldsymbol A, \boldsymbol B$ related if $\mathcal T$ has matrices under $C$ and $E$ respectively?

> If you have copied right, then direct computation shows $$[\mathcal T]_E = \begin{bmatrix}4 & a-3 & 0\\0 & 4 & 0\\-3 & 0 & -2\end{bmatrix} = \boldsymbol B,$$ then $\boldsymbol A$ and $\boldsymbol B$ are similar. Therefore at least we should have $\mathrm {tr}(\boldsymbol A) = \mathrm {tr}(\boldsymbol B)$ and $\det(\boldsymbol A) = \det (\boldsymbol B)$. According to the equation of trace, we have $$4+4-2 = 1+4+b =6 \implies b = 1,$$ but $\det(\boldsymbol A) = 40 \neq \det(\boldsymbol B) = -32$, so maybe you have copied wrong…?

#### UPDATE

Now that the OP had the question corrected, we could continue the process.

> Direct computation shows that the characteristic polynomials of $\boldsymbol A, \boldsymbol B$ are the same:$(4-c)^2(-2-c)$. So we should investigate further. Note that$$\boldsymbol A-4\boldsymbol I_3=\begin{bmatrix}-3 & 6 & -3 \\ 0&0&0 \\-3&6 &-3\end{bmatrix}$$ has rank 1, so $\dim(\mathrm {Ker(\boldsymbol A - 4\boldsymbol I)}) =2$, thus $\boldsymbol A$ could be diagonalized. Now for $\boldsymbol B$, $$\boldsymbol B - 4\boldsymbol I=\begin{bmatrix} 0& a-3 & 0\\ 0&0&0 \\-3 &0&-6\end{bmatrix}$$ should also has rank 1, so we must have $a =3$.

Comment: Yes I copied wrong, the $(3,1)$  entrance of $A$ is $-3$ and not $3$. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Firstly thanks for your answer, I am sorry, but I don't understand from your answer whether there is a simple way to find $a$?

Comment: @dan Updated. Feel free to check it.